# Laravel SQL query - long waiting time for the result

Tags: laravel, search, bigdata, phrase

I wrote a function that searches the database after the phrase.
First, I'm looking for records that have all the words from the phrase. In the second place I am looking for records, which have any word from the given phrase.

```
public static function findTitleAll($fullTextWildcards) {
    return \App\Offers::select(...)->where('active', '=', '1')->where('payed', '=', '1')
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($fullTextWildcards) {
                        $query->orWhereRaw('MATCH (title) AGAINST ("' . $fullTextWildcards . '" IN BOOLEAN MODE)');
                    });
}

public static function titleAny($findTextWildcards) {
    return \App\Offers::select(...)->where('active', '=', '1')->where('payed', '=', '1')
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($findTextWildcards) {
                        foreach ($findTextWildcards as $value) {
                            $query->orWhere('title', 'like', "%" . $value . "%");
                        }
                    });
}
```

Then merges the results without repetition $result1->merge($result2)... e.t.c.

It takes a long time to return such a result. This is not an efficient solution. How can I ask the table to get the most relevant results? the table currently has over 70,000 records.

1. A query looking for offers that have all the words from the given phrase.
2. Inquiry seeking offers that have any word from the given phrase.

Attention should be paid to problematic strings, eg: "ASP / NET / C # (java developer)" This string has special characters

Comment: What's a **long time**? 5 seconds or five hours?

Comment: Which query takes a long time? The one using `LIKE` or the one using  `MATCH` ?

Comment: Depending on the length of the phrase, the result is obtained after about 5 to 15 seconds